# use name to call data.fame and create a column on it:

Tags: r, dataframe, assign, names

I have been trying to do something like:

```
get(names[i])$column1<-vector
```

or more precisely in my case, `get(names[i])@data<-data.frame`

I have been struggling with `get()`, `assign()` searching for similar things ... but cannot figure out how to do it

example:

```
names<-c("york","paris","donostia")
vector<- 1:8
data<- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(0,9),ncol=3))
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with your example data.frame:

```
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(0,9),ncol=3))

> data
  V1 V2 V3
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0
3  0  0  0
```

If I understand your question, you want to add a column, but you want to do so referring to your data.frame by a variable that holds its name.

The syntax `df$foo <- x` is a convenience for applying a function named `$<-` that takes the data.frame `df`, a column name, and a new column and returns a new data.frame. The magic part is that it captures the return value back in original the variable `df`.

With that in mind, here's what I think you're after:

```
name <- 'data'
assign(name, `$<-`(get(name), 'new.column', letters[1:3]))

> data
  V1 V2 V3 new.column
1  0  0  0          a
2  0  0  0          b
3  0  0  0          c
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was over. I think I simplified my problem and something really weird is happening to my data.

I am actually working with a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and I am trying to replace the data.frame inside of the object (object@data).

so the beginning is an example I got from someone else:

```
    ################ data ################
    library(sp)
    grd <- GridTopology(c(1,1), c(1,1), c(3,3))
    polys <- as.SpatialPolygons.GridTopology(grd)
    centroids <- getSpPPolygonsLabptSlots(polys)
    x <- centroids[,1]
    y <- centroids[,2]
    z <- 1.4 + 0.1*x + 0.2*y + 0.002*x*x
    map <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(polys, 
                             data=data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z,                                 row.names=getSpPPolygonsIDSlots(polys)))


    ########## my case ##############
    new.data1<-data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z*2, row.names=getSpPPolygonsIDSlots(polys))
    new.data2<-data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z/2, row.names=getSpPPolygonsIDSlots(polys))
    names<-c("new.data1","new.data2")
    maps<-c("map1","map2")

    for(i in 1:length(names)){
      assign(maps[i],map) ### I copy the map in each of the maps I want

      ### and here I try to copy the new data.frames in the data slot of my maps
      assign(maps[i],`@<-`(get(maps[i]),"data",get(names[i])))
    }

    #### check
    identical(get(maps[1]),get(maps[2]))
```

I thought everything was ok, but instead, I got that the two data.frames in the different maps are the same. I got a bit lost in what I am saying in the row:

assign(maps[i],`@<-`(get(maps[i]),"data",get(names[i])))

and I think that here should be the problem. why does this last line assign the same data.frame (the last names[i]) to both new maps (map1 & map2) ????

many thanks

Comment: In this case, your local environment has entries named "map1" and "map2" that both point to the same object (whatever is returned from SpatialPolygonsDataFrame). There aren't two "maps", just two names for the same map.

Comment: I'm not sure about your goal, but using assign is probably not the best way to go about it. It looks like you want a plain old list of maps.

Answer (score 0):

Would code along these lines do the trick?

```
maps <- list()
for (name in ['city1', 'city2', ...etc...]) {
  data <- getDataForThisParticularMap(name)
  maps <- append(maps, list(SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(...etc..., data=data)))
}
```

This is what you want, if your overall goal is a list of different map objects.

Comment: yes, I think this is working. I have to find a programming tutorial to understand what you pointed out about the environments though. Many many thanks cbare